# Which linux distribution comes with python 2.6 by default?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

I am working with a legacy program written in Python 2.6. As the program is platform-specific, it can only be executed on Linux environments.

Therefore, I am wondering which Linux distribution fits my needs as my current Ubuntu system comes with >= Python 2.7 by default.

Comment: Arch has [2.6 packages](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=python26) in AUR... Although upgrading to 2.7 shouldn't be that much trouble? Perhaps you should detail your problems running the code with Python 2.7, so the *real* problem can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Upgrade your application so it at least works in Python 2.7. There should be very little that actually breaks between 2.6 and 2.7 so this would be the preferred option most of the time.

Option 2: Build Python from source. Not very hard to do and guarantees you have control over patches and updates and don't have to trust some random third party.

Option 3: Find a third-party repository with the version you need. For example see https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes and running these commands should give you a working python2.6:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get install python2.6
```

*Edit:*

After doing this you need to invoke Python 2.6 explicitly otherwise you will still get the system Python. If you really want to get python 2.6 just by typing `python` you could create a virtual environment then when that environment is active you can run python 2.6 just by typing python. Search for `virtualenv` if you want to know about virtual environments for python.

Comment: try using `python2.6` as the command to run the script instead of `python`. If the repository has installed correctly that should just work. You don't really want to make the `python` command point to 2.6 as that will mess with a lot of core Ubuntu stuff.

Comment: @Dunes mostly true, but `virtualenv` might be an option.